# how to make the tag to change its content after click?

Tags: jquery

Things like this , I use the span on click function,when it was clicked,its content will be change. I use the jquery to my form.
The code is here,How to change its text when click ?

```
<form action="">
   <span id="checkall"><a href="javascript:void(0);">select all</a></span>
   <div class="all">
       <input id="" name="" type="checkbox" /> 1
       <input id="" name="" type="checkbox" /> 2
  </div> 
</form>

$(function() {
    var obj = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
    var txt = $('#checkall').text();
    //alert(txt);
    $('#checkall').on('click', function(e) {
        obj.each(function() {
            this.checked = ! this.checked;
          // use if ( this.checked) 
            //  text change its value
        })
    })
})
```

I put the code on the jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/huapei/6UfS2/1/

Comment: I dont understand your question, please try to explain better. Maybe an small example

Comment: You click the wrong thing. Move the ID to the link, pass (e) and add e.preventDefault(); then use the data attribute to store the state

Answer (score 5):

You can use a ternary expression to change the text depending on what it says:

```
var link = $(this).find('a');
link.text() == "select all" ? link.text("un-select all") : link.text("select all");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6UfS2/2/

Comment: This doesn't handle checkbox selection. It appears to me that the original code attempted to do so.

Comment: @isherwood I don't think that sgsheg asked for how to select the checkboxes. If I understand it right, then he asked how to change the text when he does check the checkboxes. So this answer is very accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if I get your question but something like this may do the trick

```
var $this = $(this);
if ($this.text() == "select all" ) {
    $this.find('a').text("unselect all")
}
else {
    $this.find('a').text("select all")
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6UfS2/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You can add another link for uncheck action and then use `toggle` method to switch between them:

```
<span id="checkall">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="check-all">select all</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="uncheck-all">deselect all</a>
</span>
```

JS

```
$('#checkall').on('click', function (e) {
    $(this).children().toggle();
    obj.each(function () {
        this.checked = !this.checked;
    });
});
```

The benefit is that you don't have to modify JS code if you change text of the link.

http://jsfiddle.net/6UfS2/7/

Answer (score 0):

Add this line after you loop through each object: `$(this).html()`. Put the new text you want inside of the parenthesis. For example, $(this).text('Deselect all')

Answer (score 0):

If you want to toggle 'select all' 'unselect all' I suggest you dont have it on its content, but rather a variable which stores it. If you make a switch on the content of elements, you are very restricted, you can never change it's value again, or you have to change javascript to match it again.

```
var whatToDoNext=  'check';
$('#checkall').on('click', function(e) {  
    var $allCheck = $('.all').find('input[type="checkbox"]');
    if( whatToDoNext== 'check' ){ 
        $allCheck.attr('checked', true); 
        whatToDoNext= 'uncheck'; //next click has to UNcheck
    }
    else{
        $allCheck.attr('checked', false); 
        whatToDoNext= 'check'; // next click has to check
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Drat it is so slow to edit fiddles on an iPhone

I moved the ID to the link

```
$(function() {
  $('#checkall').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var obj = $('input[type="checkbox"]');
    var chk = $(this).text()=="uncheck all";
    chk = !chk;
    $(this).text(chk?"uncheck all":"check all");
    obj.each(function() {
      this.checked=chk;
    });
  });
})
```